# Where is the cli.js in protractor 5.0 and How to do protractor configuration in eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, protractor

Am trying to find cli.js  for the protractor,
There is no lib folder.There is cli.js file under built(node_modules/protractor/built).Is this the one we should use for configuring protractor in eclipse?
If i use that in eclipse it says " Client file does not exist" 
How to do protractor configuration in eclipse?

Thanks for the help

Comment: it will in `node_modules/protractor/lib`

Comment: I dont see that in my laptop (mac),under node_ modules i have only this             ➜  node_modules cd protractor
➜  protractor ls
CHANGELOG.md      DEVELOPER.md      README.md         built             exampleTypescript node_modules      tsconfig.json
CONTRIBUTING.md   LICENSE           bin               example           gulpfile.js       package.json      tslint.json

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3089-- Its under built and thats the cli.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its under `/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js`